# MenuItem background doesnt change when its highlighted

Tags: wpf, triggers, menuitem

Why it doesnt want to change its color? 
Its always highlighted with default color.

```
         <Menu>
            <Menu.Resources>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type MenuItem}">
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsHighlighted" Value="True">
                            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Black"/>
                        </Trigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
            </Menu.Resources>
            <MenuItem Header="Menu" Margin="6" Foreground="White" FontSize="14" FontFamily="Times New Roman">
                <MenuItem Header="Add Invoice" Command="{Binding AddInvoice}"/>
                <MenuItem Header="Invoices List" Command="{Binding AddInvoiceList}" FontFamily="Tahoma" />
            </MenuItem>
            <Menu.Background>
                <SolidColorBrush />
            </Menu.Background>
        </Menu>
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that your menuitem is applying to ALL of the menu items, including your main menu and submenu. This is because they are both menuitems.

To solve this, you could put a style in your window.resources, and reference that style. Also you want to use the "IsMouseOver" for the trigger.

in

```
<Window.Resources>
        <Style x:Key="MenuItemWithHighlighting"  TargetType="{x:Type MenuItem}">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver"
                         Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Foreground"
                            Value="Blue" />
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
</Window.Resources>
```

Then your menu items can reference that resource.

```
            <MenuItem Header="Menu" Margin="6" Foreground="White" FontSize="14" FontFamily="Times New Roman">
                <MenuItem Header="Add Invoice" Command="{Binding AddInvoice}"
Style={StaticResource MenuItemWithHighlighting}" />
                <MenuItem Header="Invoices List" Command="{Binding AddInvoiceList}" FontFamily="Tahoma" Style={StaticResource MenuItemWithHighlighting}" />
            </MenuItem>
```

Comment: <Style x:Key="MenuItemWithHighlighting"  TargetType="{x:Type MenuItem}">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver"
                         Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Foreground"
                            Value="Red" />
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>

Comment: That works for Foreground, which I was able to change through my code, but I want to change Background color. I found some answer on google: "The reason why the property trigger doesn't work is that the default control template of MenuItem shows a decorator on the MenuItem when the mouse is over the MenuItem, which covers the background of the MenuItem.
The solution is to implement a custom control template for MenuItem by yourself."

Comment: Yeah for foreground you can access the dependencyproperty, but for background you have to edit the template.